# Sortable table security issue

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, sql

I want to develop a sortable table where when user click on the header column, the table will retrieve the data via JSON and display it. In order for this to work, I have to put information like database column and database table name together with the column. When user clicks on it, these value will be pass to the server and retrieve updated data.

So my question is, is it safe to expose the database table and the table column name? I have been thinking of using php session to store those info and only expose the session id that link to the info. But the problem is, if I do it this way, the sorting will not works if user open multiple tab of my website.

Do you know any other better method of doing this?

Thanks.

Comment: at least it shouldn't be any security issue as long as you're note allowing sql-injection.

Comment: http://www.jeasyui.com/documentation/datagrid.php

Comment: if exposing database table and column name is confirm to be really safe, then I guess I will process with it.

Comment: Ask yourself: what can a user actually *do* knowing the table name? Does the user have any direct influence on the table name or the query being generated?

Answer (score 0):

Datatables is a jQuery plugin that does pretty much exactly what you want to do and also offers lots of different functionality. It allows you to sort tables by columns. Some examples of Datatables:
http://datatables.net/examples/

You can also get the data using ajax. Have a look at this example: http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/ajax/ajax.html

People use datatables with 20+ million rows, have a look at http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/data_sources/server_side.html

Comment: Thanks for your respond. But that sorting is 100% javascript based. If my record have 10,000 rows, the data will be very huge. Which is what I don't want. Therefore, I am preferring to call back to server and retrieve only required data for display.

Comment: too bad the table is not responsive html5

Answer (score 0):

Whenever possible I try to use integers instead of text-based keys in GET/POST, you're safe by default.

You really don't need to save the keys into a session but just translate them kind of:

```
$columns = array(
  '1' => 'UserID',
  '2' => 'FirstName
  ...
)

$order = 1;
if (isset($_REQUEST['order'])) $order = (int) $_REQUEST['order'];
$orderName = $columns[$order];
//beware the bug of unset key
//the ugly sql
$sql = 'select .. from .. order by ' . $order;
```

and in the html-grid, use

```
 <a href="?order=2"/>FirstName</a>
```

That would be the most dead simple and safe solution I can think of.

regards,